# Why isn't water decompose well like food, although bacteria need water?

Tags: bacteriology, decay

Fruits are decomposed by bacteria well.

Although bacteria need water more than other foods,
why isn't water decomposed well like food?

Comment: -1, this question makes no sense. What do you mean by water decay? I wouldn't define water as a 'food', do you have a reference that does?

Comment: To me the question indeed make some sense. "Water is inert" that is a wrong concept. Water is biologically very active and it take part in all biological pathways. But all the biochemical pathways also give out water in so many places... so water on Earth never finishes as some-other by-product like H2 + O2.

Comment: Though those fruit-rotting bacteria requires much watery condition; a large amount of water (on gross); goes to keep the bacterial cytoplasm fluidy.

Comment: Interesting thing I found in this question; if all the water got "degraded" by the bacteria into H2 + O2 ; all liquid water would finish up from Earth. However likely bacteria would not go to waste their energy via such a thermodynamically unfavorable 'endergonic' process.

Comment: Perfectly good question, for any adult teacher, to understand and answer. Pontification is not the mission of moderators. Clarification IS. Fruits contain cells and sugar which can be eaten by millions of organisms. Water is like rock, an element, and it can only give food to as many animals as it has CO2, N2, Mg, Ca, And other cell constituents dissolved in it. If the water is rich in dissolved rocks and nitrogen, it will produce a lot of life. Stagnant water is older and gives life an easier place to live, and is less filtered by algea.

Comment: I agree. The web site is not like a book or Wikipedia. In the original web site, Stack Overflow, users help each other even if the question is duplicated or unclear, by trying to understand what the questioner wants to know, also the answerer shows the link of other answers, when it is duplicated. So I believe that kind of behaviour is needed in this biology section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you mean by "decay".

Water is not an organic compound (it contains no carbon). It is just $H_2O$. Water cannot rot! Water is typically not considered as "food" as it is not a source of carbon.

Living organisms can split water molecule (through photosynthesis typically, see wiki > [water splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_splitting)) and synthesize water molecule (through formation of carbon polymers typically) but I doubt this is what you were thinking about.

Note that if you leave water with a source of carbon (dirty water) somewhere, many organisms will be happy to colonize this environment.

Comment: -1, I can't see any value in answer a question that is _totally_ unclear.

Comment: I've got another answer from other site, water has no nutritious value. So as you mentioned, in dirty water, bacteria can colonize. Hence we can leave a bottle of water on a desk for a long time. Probably dirty water can be decayed. But the bottled water has also an expiration date, right? I was curious for it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Michael_A An answer should not be judged based on the question. It is not easy to ask clear questions on subject you know little about. I have asked a lot of unclear questions and comments and short answers have helped me even if the question ends up being closed. It would be silly to rebuke any attempt at helping someone just because (s)he failed to formulate a clear question (except maybe when the post clearly shows lack of effort).

Comment: @Remi.b, I agree with your reply but I don't think it's relevant to this question + answer. Many very useful answers correct a false premise in the question, I have read, and enjoyed, a number of your answers that were very useful in that regard. It's not clear that you have corrected any false premises with the answer. The comment from Solek indicates that another site provided an answer to whatever the question _was_. I think this question shows a very clear lack of effort.

Comment: I agree there might have more helpful answer in explaining the basics of organic chemistry and why water will not rot. Note btw that I did vote to close the question as unclear right after you did (as it will become obvious if it eventually ever closes).

Comment: @Solek Based on your comment, I feel like you are still thinking that water can be decayed. That expiration date on the water bottles is for the plastic that starts leaching chemicals into water. Example can be found in this paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Victor_Mihucz/publication/26239236_Leaching_of_antimony_from_polyethylene_terephthalate_PET_bottles_into_mineral_water_Sci_Total_Environ/links/56e6480f08ae65dd4cc0e54a.pdf). Water can be contaminated with waste but not decayed.

Comment: I don't think not being an organic compound is the relevant factor here.  After all, you could say that iron 'rots' when it rusts.  What's important is that rot is a bunch of exothermic reactions, so breaking down those organic compounds supplies energy to the microorganisms responsible for it.  Splitting water is an endothermic reaction: you have to put a good bit of energy in to split the molecule.

Comment: @Remi.b actually, answers *should* be judged based on the question. From [How do I write a good answer?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`*

Comment: @Remi.b it's actually one of my canned comments that I [posted on Meta](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/what-are-some-good-informative-comments-i-can-leave-for-new-users) a while back. It's meant for the occasions when people try to answer god-awful questions where nothing is clear, or there's no research effort whatsoever and the question could be answered by googling the question title, or whatever.

Comment: @MattDMo, that was the section I was thinking of with my initial comments. I couldn't locate it.   I remember reading that and thinking, those are some wise words.

Comment: I thank Remi.b much for answering this question, especially when I see other comments.